# How to read text file from Snort?

Tags: text, command-line, snort, intrusion-detection

I have a worm that its signature is in .txt file. Now I wanna check it with `Snort` IDS. I read the the manual page of `Snort`, But I couldn't find anything. How can I do this?(Is there a command for detecting worms signature using `Snort` something like `snort -r worm.txt -c /etc/snort/snort.conf` ?)

Answer (score 0):

Try to send this file with "nc" in your local machine (just an idea)

You will need two terminal and Snort must be listening in you network interface  :

The first terminal

```
nc -l 1234 > filename.out
```

The first terminal

```
nc host.example.com 1234 < Worm.txt
```